# Trigger an event in the popup from a parent

Tags: javascript, popup

I have two windows , the second is a popup , and I want to trigger an event from the parent (the first one where I have a link to this popup).

here's a javascript code for the trigger (in the parent window's javascript code):

```
winPop=window.open(opts.url,opts.nom,"width="+opts.width+",height="+opts.height+",top="+opts.top+",left="+opts.left);

    winPop.onload=function(){

     $(winPop.document).trigger('connected', {
      jid: "jid",
      password: '123'
     });

    }
```

This javascript code launchs the popup and tries to trigger an event bound in popup (ready) function:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $(document).bind('connected', function () {
  alert("Hello , I'm here");
 });
```

The problem is that using the previous javascript code .. the bound event is not triggered as predicted.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you include the jquery libraries?

Comment: Yes of course  ... all jquery code is working good in the whole project, except this one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had done this earlier with something like this:

```
var realWindowOpen = window.open;
window.open = wrappedWindowOpen;
function wrappedWindowOpen(url, name, specs, replace) {
    window.open = realWindowOpen;
    var windowHandle = window.open(url, name, specs, replace);
    if (windowHandle)
        console.log("New Popup Window created: ", {name:name});
    else
        console.error("New Window Failed. " + {name:name});

    if (popupFnCreationNotify) {
        popupFnCreationNotify(windowHandle);
        popupFnCreationNotify = null;
    }
    window.open = wrappedWindowOpen;
}

// Calling example
var popupFnCreationNotify = function() {
    console.log("I got called back");
};
window.open("my url");
```

Please note:

- realWindowOpen always points to window.open.
- I wrap the actual window.open with wrappedWindowOpen as you can see in the code.
- Before calling window.open, the caller sets the popupFnCreationNotify to any callback function they wish.

Comment: I can't understand from where you got the realWindowOpen variable, and the popupFnCreationNotify..

Also, I use the Jquery, so is there any method to use with jQuery to get the same task done? (I mean with a trigger() function)

Comment: This code is fully compatible with JQuery, infact part of my JQueryUI plugin called PopupManager. Earlier for you, I had just cut pasted the code from there, that's why it was difficult to understand. The self in earlier code was actually pointing to the plugin instance.

Comment: Okey, Friend .. thank you for your answer, I will try this methed and +1 :)